# What does the word “potential” describe, “products” or “impact”?

Tags: american-english, parsing, adjective-phrases, attributive-nouns

> Has an assessment been conducted to evaluate **potential products impact** due to this nonconformity?

This is a sentence written by an American . I would like to know what does the word “potential” describe,  “***products***” or “***impact***” ?

Comment: Is there a larger conversation in place that can give some sort of context? I *suspect* that it's referring to the potential impact of the product's nonconformity, and that the sentence might be poorly constructed.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: this answer is based on my understanding of the text, which may be wrong, since I don't have the full context. I read *products* here as "things that are made to be sold", so this could be some marketing or management text.)

The sentence talks about nonconformity, which means something does not meet some requirement.

On first reading it seems that the nonconformity is a *problem of the products* and thus *the products can have an impact*. In this reading, "potential" refers to the impact. But if that were the case, then an apostrophe should have been used: either "potential product's impact" or "potential products' impact" ("have" is contracted to the possessive ending *'s*).

I would instead suggest that there is a nonconformity of some part or ingredient, which might have an *impact on products* using that part or ingredient. (Note: impact **on**, not **of**, products).

With this interpretation, the sentence could be written in simpler language as:

> Did anyone assess the impact on potential products that this nonconformity might have?

And here "potential" clearly refers to the product.

Since this analysis is mainly based on the subtle lack of an apostrophe, which is not pronounced anyway, it is hard to tell. I would advise writers to use language carefully to avoid possible ambiguity as in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: "Has an assessment been conducted to evaluate [the] potential product's impact [since it is not like other products on the market]?"

Long Answer: This is just a guess. I would need more context to be able to better help you.

In the meantime, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Words ending in *-al* and especially *-tial* generally don't modify other modifiers unless they are changed to *-ally* or *-tially*, which makes them an adverb.

So *potential* and *products* both modify *impact.*

Comment: Thanks for help !  could you please explain more ?  Thank you !!!

Comment: why **potential** and **products** both modify **impact**  not only **products** ?

Comment: For *potential* to modify *products* it would have to be an adverb.  *Potential* is not an adverb but *potentially* is.  So it can only modify the first noun that comes afterward.

Comment: Thanks !  _potential_ is a adj , _products_ is a noun , why can't modify _products_ ?  Thank you !

Comment: Nope, *products* (and it should be spelled *product's*) is a possessive adjective describing *impact*.  (You are evaluating the *impact **of*** the product, not the product itself.)  Adjectives can normally be removed and the sentence will still make sense, and you can do this in that sentence: "... to evaluate impact due to this nonconformity."

Comment: _In circumstances where the company needs to amend a **permanent**  employees rostered day off, the employee will be provided with at least 1 week of notice._ in this sentence , the word _**permanent**_ modifies _**rostered day off**_,right ? as you said if  _**employees**_  was removed , the sentence still makes sense.  thank you very much !

Comment: You found a flaw in my heuristic above, which might have been too simple now that I think about it.  *Permanent* is definitely modifying *employee's* - but the entire phrase *permanent employee's* is itself functioning like a one-word adjective to *day off*.  I *think* the two words make what's called an "adjectival phrase."  Technically it makes *permanent* an adverb but it's more useful to simply consider "permanent employee" an adjective.  And that's common in English for phrases to occupy spots where single words can go.  Maybe someone better with terminology can jump in here.